# Manipulate Dataframe Values to Converge on a Weight Assigned to It

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have an interesting problem that I could not seem to find anywhere. I am hoping someone can help me with this.

I have a dataframe of values, each of these values has a weight assigned to them (e.g. 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.09, 0.01) and I want to take the dataframe I have with those weights and duplicate values such that the dataframe has 40% of my 0.4 weighted values, 30% of my 0.3 weighted values, etc.

```
rand = np.sort(np.random.randint(700, 12000, 20))
df = pd.DataFrame(rand, columns=["Value"])
df["Weight"] = 0.01
df.loc[0:2, "Weight"] = 0.4; df.loc[2:6, "Weight"] = 0.3
df.loc[7, "Weight"] = 0.2; df.loc[8:15, "Weight"] = 0.09
```

Above is my sample dataframe. As you can see I have two values weighted to be 40% of the data set so I need to find a way to duplicate them, as well as the others such that they converge to their allocated weights.

I have values in this dataset that I assigned a weight of 40%, but those values only occur twice in that dataset indicating that it shows up just 10% of the time. I want to manipulate the dataframe by duplicating them (or some other way) such they are 40% of the dataset.

In the data set I am dealing with I am loading in the data from a couple different excel files then assign their weights based on some other criteria.

Here is an example of what I am trying to get at. I made it in excel, as you can see as I am adding duplicates to the data set I get closer and closer to my desired weights.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: The way your problem is worded is not very clear.
It is not possible to have 2 values that make up 40% of the records each, 5 that are 30% each, etc. and have the total add up to 100% no matter how many times you duplicate the rows. If the weights are also intended to be updated, you need to explain how.

Comment: @DamianSatterthwaite-Phillips I see what you were getting at now. I dont want each value to be 40%. I want ALL values that have a desired weight of 40% to be duplicated until they do make up 40% of the data set. I added additional information to my problem statement, hopefully the example helps a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You can group all of the values with the same weight using `.groupby()` and `.agg()`, use `.apply()` to sample based on the weights, and then use `.explode()` to transform the samples into individual rows:

```py
from math import ceil

df = df.groupby("Weight").agg({"Value": list}).reset_index()
df["Value"] = df.apply(
    (
        lambda row:
            np.random.choice(
                row["Value"],
                ceil(len(row["Value"]) * row["Weight"]),
                replace=False
            )
    ),
    axis=1
)
df = df.explode("Value")
```

This outputs:

```py
   Weight  Value
0    0.01  10809
1    0.09   7110
2    0.20   6418
3    0.30   5870
3    0.30   6331
4    0.40   2207
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BrokenBenchmark I added some additional information to my question. I am more looking to take all of my values that have an assigned weight of 0.4 and make all of them (maybe by duplication) occur 40% of the time in my data set. And then have the values with 0.3 be the same etc.

Comment: Got it. So the algorithm would uniformly sample from the possible values for each weight?

Comment: I envision it doing something like 1. Duplicating the values that have 0.4 weights until they are occurring 40% of the time in the data set, 2. Do the same for the values assigned 0.3 weight, 3. Go back and make sure 0.4 weighted values are still within a tolerance of desired 40% if not duplicate more values etc. etc. Not sure if there is a more elegant way but it is the only way my mind sees it right now. Hopefully this helps!